# Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f'(x)$ cannot both exist.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable in some interval contain $a$ but that $f'$ is discontinous at $a$. Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f'(x)$ cannot  both exist.

> **Attempt**: I think the question should have instead been phrased as : **prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f'(x)$ both cannot be equal and finite**

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f'(x)=l$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f'(x)=m~|~l \ne m$, then $f'$ is still discontinuous at $a$ because the limit itself doesn't exist.

On the other hand, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-} f'(x)=p=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f'(x)$, then, $f'(a)=p$ itself.

Please tell me what do you think. Is the question correctly phrased?

> If any of the one sided limit exists and other doesn't, then won't the function cease to be differentiable?

Comment: A limit not being finite is equivalent to it not existing, I think.

Comment: @Dayton What I mean to say is that could be *one* of the many reasons a limit doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Tavish here i am talking about the one sided limits. hence, we can talk about their exitence separately

Comment: Yes. The limit from one side will be equal to $\infty$ and from the other side, $-\infty$, so neither of them exists.

Comment: *both cannot* exist or *cannot both* exist?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I am sorry, yes, the book says " cannot both exist. Could you please describe the difference between the two usage of words

Comment: That's a relief.  I'm working on an answer; stay tuned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big difference between saying that the two one-sided limits of $f$' *both cannot exist.* or *cannot both exist*.

- *both cannot exist* means that the left-hand limit cannot exist, *and* the right-hand limit cannot exist.
- *cannot both exist* means it's impossible that the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit to both exist.  By De Morgan's law, it's equivalent to saying that either the left-hand limit cannot exist, *or* the right-hand limit cannot exist (or both).

The first statement (*both cannot exist*) is false.  Consider
$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 0 \\
                        x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$, $f'$ is not continuous at $0$, but $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x) = 0$.  The other one-sided limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$ does not exist.

After comments, you clarified that the second statement (*cannot both exist*) is the intended one.  In that case,  I think the question is correctly phrased.  The contrapositive statement might make more sense:

> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable near $a$.  If $\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$ exist [and are finite], then $f'$ is continuous at $a$.

I put *and are finite* in brackets because it's assumed that when a limit “exists” we're talking about a finite number.  An infinite limit doesn't “exist.”  This is complicated because we use (some might say abuse) the equals sign in both cases.  We say $\lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$, but the first limit “exists” while the second does not.

To dig a bit deeper, you need to show that: if $f$ is differentiable near $a$, and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$ exists, then
$$
    \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)
$$
and the the same thing with $x\to a^+$ replaced by $x\to a^{-}$.  For this,
the Mean Value Theorem is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got a query please. Suppose if $f$ is differentiable near $a$, and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$ as well as $\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x)$ exists but they are not equal, what  can we say about $f'(a)$? I think $f'$ is still discontinuous at $a$ because the limits are not equal ? Am i correct?

Comment: This problem is saying that that situation will never happen.  If the one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to a^\pm} f'(x)$ exist but disagree, then $f$ cannot be differentiable at $a$.

Comment: @mathew Leingang exactly!

Comment: Thank you very much . It's clear to me now

Comment: @Matthew Leingang What about only 1 of the one-sided limits existing? Would that be allowed, or possible?

Comment: OP's question appears in Calculus by Spivak, 3rd Ed. Chapter 11 exercise 55. I'm writing this here so this question is better indexed for others searching for info about the exercise.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang ah, please nevermind. I see you already provided an example of this. I think I was thinking, "if only 1 one-sided limit exists, how can the derivative exist," confusing the limit of derivatives approaching a point, with the actual limit that defines the definitive. Good lesson.